# What is the best way to see a sample of all your databases and tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, database, sample

What is the best way to see a sample of all your databases and tables in one query?

For example: `while (show databases) { foreach database_name (select * from table_name limit 2)};`

[Test_DB]
Test_DB.one

```
+---------------+--------------+
| ip            | tstamp       |
+---------------+--------------+
| 192.168.10.10 | 01/13/2013   |
| 192.168.10.11 | 01/14/2013   |
+---------------+--------------+
```

[Test_DB]
Test_DB.two

```
+----------------+--------------+
| mac            | tstamp       |
+----------------+--------------+
| dead.beef.cake | 01/13/2013   |
| dead.beef.cake | 01/14/2013   |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: There's nothing built-in that I know of. You could write a stored procedure that creates dynamic queries from `information_schema.table.tables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick list you can do this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS _db, TABLE_NAME AS _table FROM information_schema.tables
```

You'll have to wrap something around that to do the `SELECT * ... LIMIT 2` part.

Comment: Thanks, I will use yours and @SamySammour's ideas in my perl script.

Answer (score 0):

"select * from [Test_DB] Test_DB.one inner join [Test_DB] Test_DB.two limit 2"
try this

Comment: Thanks, I will use yours and @tadman's ideas in my perl script.